# how is weighs defined in opencv svm

Tags: opencv, svm

I have simple question about svm weights. I am doing a binary classification. I want to set different weights for two classes. My code is like this

```
Mat weights = (Mat_<double>(2,1)<<1,2);
CvMat weight = weights;
param.class_weights = &weight;
```

I am wondering which weight is for which class? I didn't it from opencv document. thanks.

Comment: I think they are the weights of each samples you trained. For example, if you have n variables and trained with m samples, your weight is probably m x n. This is my guess.

Comment: maybe you can save svm model first. and check class_labels item. the class_weights and class_labels should be in same order

Answer (score 0):

> classWeights – Optional weights in the C_SVC problem , assigned to particular classes. They are multiplied by C so the parameter C of class #i becomes classWeights(i) * C. Thus these weights affect the misclassification penalty for different classes. The larger weight, the larger penalty on misclassification of data from the corresponding class.